# How to plot particle trajectory in paraview

Tags: paraview, particles, openfoam

I have Lagrangian data (particle id, diameter, and velocity) came from particulate flow simulation with OpenFOAM and I wanted to plot the particle trajectories inside the paraview. I have created the VTK files through the time.

Comment: Hello Behzad. Would you mind sharing some files ?

Comment: This likely requires multiple steps to do in ParaView and without the data to work with it will be difficult to describe the needed process to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following method:
crate VTK of lagrangian data
Load data in ParaView
Use the "*temporalPaticlesToPathlines*" filter

make sure to have a unique identifier for the particles. I used origId and it is not always unique if you have breakup of particles.